# How we can add prisma middleware in different file?

Tags: middleware, prisma, prism-4

I have multiple middleware for a single route. can i breakdown code and move middleware in different file?.I tried with import a middleware in server file but it is not working

Comment: Could you please provide more details or code snippets of what you have tried so far? Otherwise it's hard to debug or guess what might have gone wrong.

Comment: import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma: PrismaClient = new PrismaClient()

prisma.$use(async (params: Prisma.MiddlewareParams, next) => {
    if (params.action == 'create' && params.model == 'User') {
        let user = params.args.data
        let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt)
        user.password = hash
    }
    return await next(params)
})

i try to add in a middleware directory of a project and want to run during a new user is created.

Comment: If possible, please update the original question, code is very hard to read from replies like this. 

Additionally, if possible, please provide all relevant code (along with which file it is associated with). For example: The code for the middleware, the code for the route/controller where the middleware is called. etc.

Comment: i am trying like these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68453660/how-to-add-a-prisma-middleware-in-different-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add like these

```
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma: PrismaClient = new PrismaClient()

prisma.$use(async (params: Prisma.MiddlewareParams, next) => {
    if (params.action == 'create' && params.model == 'User') {
        let user = params.args.data
        let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt)
        user.password = hash
    }
    return await next(params)
})
```

Comment: I put this code in main.ts file in Nestjs but it's not work