# How to add a prisma middleware in different file

Tags: typescript, orm, prisma

I am trying to use Prisma middleware to hash passwords. For hashing, I created a new directory (middleware) and created a new file prisma.ts inside it. Now I want to access these middleware, whenever a new user is created.

```
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma: PrismaClient = new PrismaClient()

prisma.$use(async (params: Prisma.MiddlewareParams, next) => {
    if (params.action == 'create' && params.model == 'User') {
        let user = params.args.data
        let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt)
        user.password = hash
    }
    return await next(params)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// File: prisma.ts

import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'
import * as middleware from './prismaMiddleware';

const prisma: PrismaClient = new PrismaClient();

prisma.$use(middleware.Encrypt);

// File: prismaMiddleware.ts
import {Prisma} from '@prisma/client';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
export const Encrypt: Prisma.Middleware =  async (params: Prisma.MiddlewareParams, next) => {
    if (params.action == 'create' && params.model == 'User') {
        let user = params.args.data
        let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt)
        user.password = hash
    }
    return await next(params)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can import `prisma` in the new file you create and then define your middleware there.

Comment: yes currently i am working with these. , but i want to remove the middleware from controller and put it in to different space. is it possible

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned above, you can put the middleware anywhere as long as you create it with the same `prisma` variable above. Make sure that `prisma` is imported in the middleware file and create the middleware there.

Comment: yes i have created on that way. but its not working. please have a look at code.

Comment: The code looks correct. What's the issue you're facing?